# Getting errors and warnings with json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, json-ld

Below is my Json data that I am trying to represent using Json-LD :

```
var schemaOrg = angular.toJson({
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "RealEstateAgent",
        "RealEstateAgent": {
                "@type": "RealEstateAgent",
                "address": "123, Xyz Tower, ajkshjask", 
                "areaServed": "Chicago",
                "brand": "My Brand",
                "email": "abc@gmail.com", 
                "knowsLanguage": "English",
                "legalName": "Jerry Kon", 
                "image": "http:samplepic.com",
                "description": "I am great",
                "name": "Jerry Kon",
                "url": "http:myprofilepic.com",
                "Telephone": "1234567899"
            }
    });
```

This is how I am rendering it:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="json-ld-music-group"></script>

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                        var jsonLd = angular.element(document.getElementById('json-ld-music-group'))[0];
                        console.log(jsonLd);
                        jsonLd.innerHTML = schemaOrg;
                        console.log(jsonLd.innerHTML);
                    });
```

Now when I copy paste entire HTML and trying to test in Google Structured Data Testing tool, then this is what I am getting:

[image]

But I am getting warning and error which I dont understand why. I already have `name and image` property in my data and its showing error on that. Also I have address, telephone and its still showing warning on that.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a RealEstateAgent inside a RealEstateAgent which is not valid. Flatten it down to the one and it is fine:

```
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "RealEstateAgent",
      "address": "123, Xyz Tower, ajkshjask", 
      "areaServed": "Chicago",
      "brand": "My Brand",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com", 
      "knowsLanguage": "English",
      "legalName": "Jerry Kon", 
      "image": "http:samplepic.com",
      "description": "I am great",
      "name": "Jerry Kon",
      "url": "http:myprofilepic.com",
      "Telephone": "1234567899"            
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and this indeed works. bdw lets say I want to represent House and Product on the same page, so how do I do that? Can you show any sample in your answer please?

Comment: I suggest you make that a new question so others will see it. I'm not an expert in this vertical. And include the context. e.g. are you a real estate agent that sells houses.